# Content Search Web Part to return task lists with specific fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, content-search-web-part

I have several task lists with a task progress field:

[image]

I want my Content Search Web Part to return links to task lists that contain the term "Overdue" in a task progress field.

I am new to this Web Part, and unsure how best to write the query logic:

[image]

Please advise.